# From array to object convert to obtain object pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have an array of object from which I have to pick one object of an array; And convert it into a pattern.

```
[ 
    executed:[
    {_id: "5f23d394cd 480e300", field: "name", value: "Jolly", operator: "equal"},
    {_id: "5f30d39f4cd8d0e301", field: "status", value: "EXPIRED", operator: "equal"},
    {_id: "5f230d39001480e302", field: "grp", value: "874-3-11-4-56", operator: "equal"},
    {_id: "59f4cd8d001480e303", field: "grp", value: "873-5-12-4-77", operator: "equal"}
    ],
    created_at: "2020-07-30T18:11:05.992Z"
    name: "Kind Find"
    _id: "1f230d39f4cd8d441480e2dd"
]
```

I have this above pattern that I am trying to convert into below one..

```
{
    "grp": ["874-3-11-4-56", "873-5-12-4-77"],
    "name": "Jolly",
    "status": "EXPIRED"
}
```

So the data inside of `executed` is only I want to pick and convert it to above like object.
Now the catch is data is dynamic that `field` and `value` would be different every time. But It just require to work with those two fields only.

Also field `grp` will always be an array....(if there's one `grp` then also it should be an array)

I am stuck with this key thing, Was new to JS(was python developer :D), exploring the areas with React.
Please help me to get this resolved.

Much Thanks!

Edit: Just another example

Example-

```
[ 
        executed:[
        {_id: "5f23d394cd 480e300", field: "name", value: "Jolly", operator: "equal"},
        {_id: "5f30d39f4cd8d0e301", field: "status", value: "EXPIRED", operator: "equal"},
        {_id: "59f4cd8d001480e303", field: "grp", value: "873-5-12-4-77", operator: "equal"}
        ],
        created_at: "2020-07-30T18:11:05.992Z"
        name: "Kind Find"
        _id: "1f230d39f4cd8d441480e2dd"
    ]
```

Output

```
  {
        "grp": ["873-5-12-4-77"],
        "name": "Jolly",
        "status": "EXPIRED"
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'field' would be different every time? do you always try to group 'grp' in an array or could that change?

Comment: Can `field: "name"` occur twice? If yes, should it be an array in the output?

Comment: Yes, if field occur twice then it should get an array, (by default `grp` would be an array no matter if its one time or two time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
const data = { 
    executed:[
    {_id: "5f23d394cd 480e300", field: "name", value: "Jolly", operator: "equal"},
    {_id: "5f30d39f4cd8d0e301", field: "status", value: "EXPIRED", operator: "equal"},
    {_id: "5f230d39001480e302", field: "grp", value: "874-3-11-4-56", operator: "equal"},
    {_id: "59f4cd8d001480e303", field: "grp", value: "873-5-12-4-77", operator: "equal"}
    ],
    created_at: "2020-07-30T18:11:05.992Z",
    name: "Kind Find",
    _id: "1f230d39f4cd8d441480e2dd"
}

console.log(
    data.executed.reduce((carry, current) => {
        if (current.field === 'grp') {
            carry[current.field] = (carry[current.field] || []).concat(current.value);
        } else {
            carry[current.field] = carry[current.field] ? [carry[current.field], current.value] : current.value;
        }
        return carry;
    }, {})
);
```

Comment: `[carry[current.field], current.value]` will create nested arrays in every iteration if there are more than 2 items with same `field`